# data binding information from knockoutjs to the view page - info not showing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In my javascript file i have mix of knockout and jquery which contains two different view models and i am having trouble displaying the results:

Javascript:

**POSITION ViewModel**

```
var positionViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.PositionName = ko.observable(data.PositionName);
        _self.PositionRank = ko.observable(data.PositionRank);
        _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
    }

    positionViewModel.AddPositions = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            positionViewModel.PushPosition(value);
        });
    };

    positionViewModel.PushPosition = function (postion) {
        viewModel.PositionTypes.push(new positionViewModel(position));
    };
```

**USER ViewModel**

```
    // the ViewModel for a single User
    var userViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
        _self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        _self.Email = ko.observable(data.Email);
        _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
    };

    userViewModel.AddUsers = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            userViewModel.PushUser(value);
        });
    };


    userViewModel.PushUser = function (user) {
        viewModel.Users.push(new userViewModel(user));
    };
```

**Positions and Users**

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.PositionTypes(), function(position){    
     var usersInPosition = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.Users(), function(user){
          return user.ContentRole() == position.ContentRole();
     });
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(usersInPosition, function(user){        

    });
});
```

**Binding**

```
// Binds the main ViewModel
var bindModel = function (data) {
    var _self = viewModel;

    viewModel.TotalUser = ko.computed(function () {
        return _self.Users().length;
    });

    userViewModel.AddUsers(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#UserView')[0]);
};
```

**View Page**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:PositionTypes">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <span data-bind="text:PositionName"></span>
                </div>
                <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'grid', foreach: Users}">

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Result example:

CEO
James

Vice President
John

Workers
Amy
Betsy

How can i alter my view to properly display results from javascript file?

Comment: How are you applying the ko bindings?

Comment: What troubles do you have? What is not working?

Comment: @edhedges i updated my post that shows my bindings above - thanks

Comment: @nemesv the positions names are not showing and within the positions are the names of users. I could show the name of the users if i don't loop within the positions but because i want to show the position title and users within

Comment: How does your PositionTypes and Users are related? I don't see a `Users` property on your POSITION ViewModel...

Comment: @nemesv position and user models are related based on the ContentRole. Sorry i forgot to add the `arrayForEach` between the two... added above. I think i am not connecting the information properly but not sure how

Comment: In your Binding section what is `viewModel`? It would be easier if you created a jsfiddle and linked it.

Comment: @edhedges i will try to create a jsfiddle for it to share

Comment: @edhedges would this work as a start: http://jsfiddle.net/zBmSN/

Comment: I see what the problem is and your architecture if off I will be answering in a second with an updated jsfiddle. It's going to be bare bones, but you need to be able to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

So your architecture was wrong to start out. In your example you are showing a list of type `Position` and each `Position` has another list of type `User`. I have whipped up a fiddle with the correct architecture for you to be able to add on whatever functionality you need. I would seriously look into the knockout documentation as well as design a little bit before you start coding.

http://jsfiddle.net/zBmSN/1/

Comment: Thanks - i appreciate the help. But i was wondering because i want to create a linq query like that will return the users for each position like maybe: `linq.From(PositionTypes).ForEach(users in Users where PositionTypes.ContentRole == Users.ContentRole) select users`?

Comment: This seems like a different problem. Create a function in the master viewmodel that does this.